# Como excluir um item do carrinho? - session

Tags: php, session

Olá, estou fazendo um carrinho de compras e não estou conseguindo excluir um item da session. Já tentei de várias formas, mas não entendi por que não funciona. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? (sou nova no php)

CÓDIGO:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
</head>
<?php
include("partials/conexao.php");
 session_start();
 if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho']))
 {
    $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
   }

    //adiciona produto
    if(isset($_GET['add']))
    {
      //ADICIONAR CARRINHO

      if($_GET['add']) {
       $id = intval($_GET['add']);
      if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]))
      {
         $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = 1; }
      else{ $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] += 1;
      }
    }


    //REMOVER CARRINHO
    if(isset($_GET['del'][$id]))
    {
      $id = intval($_GET['add']);
      if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]))
      {
        unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
      }
    }
    //ALTERAR QUANTIDADE
     if($_GET['add']) {
        if(is_array($_POST['prod'])){
          foreach($_POST['prod'] as $id => $qtd){
                     $id  = intval($id);
                     $qtd = intval($qtd);
                     if(!empty($qtd) || $qtd <> 0)
                     {
                        $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = $qtd;
                     }else{
                        unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
                     }
                  }
               }
            }

      //ESVAZIAR carrinho
        if ($_GET['empty']){
          unset($_SESSION['carrinho']);

        }

         }


 <!-- carrinho menu-->
 <?php include("partials/header.php");?>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="carrinhobg">
      <form action="carrinho.php" method="get" onsubmit="">
      <div class="txt-heading">Carrinho
        <a id="btnEmpty"
        href="carrinho.php?empty"/>Esvaziar carrinho</a>
      </form>
      <form action="carrinho.php" method="post">
      </div>

        <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
          <?php
          if(count($_SESSION['carrinho']) == 0){ ?>
            <?php echo '<h4 class="nomargin"> Não há produto no carrinho </h4>'; ?>
            <?php }
            else {
              $total = 0;
              foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd){
                $sql   = "SELECT *  FROM vw_produtos WHERE cd_produto= '$id'";
                $qr    = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                $ln    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);

                $nome  = $ln['nm_produto'];
                $preco = number_format($ln['vl_produto'], 2, ',', '.');
                $sub   = number_format($ln['vl_produto'] * $qtd, 2, ',', '.');

                $total += $ln['vl_produto'] * $qtd;
                ?>
                        <thead>
                  <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:50%">Produto</th>
                                <th style="width:10%">Preço</th>
                                <th style="width:8%">Quantidade</th>
                                <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                                <th style="width:10%">Retirar da cesta</th>
                            </tr>

                        </thead>

                            <tr>
                                <td data-th="Produto">
                                    <div class="row">

                                        <div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs">
                      <img src="img/produtos/<?php echo $ln['imagem']?>" alt="..." class="img-responsive"/></div>

                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 class="nomargin"><?php echo $ln['nm_produto']?></h4>
                           <p class=""> <?php echo $ln['ds_produto']?>
                             </p>
                                        </div>

                                </td>
                                <td data-th="Preço"> <?php echo $ln['vl_produto']?>  </td>
                                <td data-th="Quantidade">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" name="prod"<?php echo '['.$id.']" value="'.$qtd.'"'?>""/>

                                </td>
                                <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center"> <?php echo 'R$' .$sub; ?> </td>
                                </td>
                </form>
                <?php //$id = $_GET['add']; ?>
                <form class="carrinho.php" method="get">
                  <td data-th="excluir" class="text-center">
                    <a href="carrinho.php?del=<?php echo $id; ?>"/> Excluir </td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
            </div>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                <?php } ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="produtos.php" class="btn btn-warning">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue comprando</a></td>
                                <td colspan="3" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                                <td class="hidden-xs text-center" ><strong>
                      <?php echo 'Total: '.'R$' .$total; ?>
                      </strong>
                    </td>
                    <?php  } ?>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
                  <div class="comprar">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="javascript: location.href='pedido-final.php'">Comprar</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="att">
                    <a href="carrinho.php" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="<?php
                     echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT='3;URL=carrinho.php'>";
                    ?>">Atualizar carrinho</a>
                  </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th style="width:50%"><b>CALCULAR FRETE</b></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                                 <div id="custom-search-inputii">
                                                  <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                                                      <input type="text" class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Digite um cep válido" />
                                                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                          <button class="btn btn-default btn-md" type="button">
                                                              Calcular
                                                          </button>
                                                      </span>
                                                  </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>
 <!--/.CONTAINER .ROW -->
                 </div>
                 </div>
         <!-- Footer -->

     <!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você que está começando, é MUITO importante manter um padrão de **indentação do código** -- são esses espaços que colocamos, ao abrir uma {} por exemplo. Isso vai te ajudar a localizar erros simples como um dos que há nesse teu código.

```
//adiciona produto
if(isset($_GET['add']))
{
    //ADICIONAR CARRINHO

    if($_GET['add']) {
        $id = intval($_GET['add']);
        if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]))
        {
            $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = 1;
        } else {
            $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] += 1;
        }
    }


    //REMOVER CARRINHO
    if(isset($_GET['del'][$id]))
    {
        $id = intval($_GET['add']);
        if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]))
        {
            unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
        }
    }
```

Perceba que o código que inclui e exclui estão dentro do bloco do mesmo **`if`** , o que testa se foi enviado um comando de adição `if (isset($_GET['add']))`

Também é importante revisar a lógica.

Você obtém o "id" que deseja excluir nesse trecho `$id = intval($_GET['add']);`

e para excluir:

```
if(isset($_GET['del'][$id]))
{
    $id = intval($_GET['add']);
```

Percebeu? Está tentando obter o ID na variável que deve "adicionar".

Revise seu código, e vá testando aos poucos. Se preciso, comece do zero com cada função: add, edit, del, clean.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Nossa muito obrigada! Troquei isso e funcionou. Pegarei teus conselhos para não acontecer outra vez. Valeu! ;)

Comment: Vale a pena ressaltar que mysql_query está depreciado e só está incluso até o PHP 5. Outras alternativas são mysqli e PDO_MySQL. (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysql.php)

Comment: @JúliaCristina boa a dica do @LipESprY ! Aprenda a usar o [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) que é uma biblioteca mais moderna. Esse site [PHP The Right Way](http://br.phptherightway.com/) tem várias dicas importantes sobre o PHP moderno!

Comment: Obrigada pela dica! Eu comecei a estudar PDO há pouco dias. Entrarei no site p/ saber mais. @LipEsprY

Comment: @JúliaCristina A ideia do lucasvscn é boa! O *PDO* perde em desempenho, comparado ao *mysqli*. Mas é tão pouco que prefro o *PDO* pela funcionalidade e compatibilidade com outros *Bancos de dados*.  Minha recomendação é investir em POO. Um *EXCELENTE* curso **GRATUITO** é do *Curso em Vídeo*: (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHz_AreHm4dmGuLII3tsvryMMD7VgcT7x).